# AWS EKS with Fargate

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, kubernetes-statefulset

I deployed a EKS with Fargate in AWS. Is it possible to deploy a statefulset database in EKS with Fargate? If it possible then how we can implement it? Can anyone help me?

I deployed the EKS with Fargate and trying to deploy a MySQL as statefulset with EFS file system attached and it doesn't show any errors or logs it deployed as statefulset but when checking logs doesn't show anything. And I'm not able to run the mysql command inside the pod. Shows access denied when run the `mysql -u root -p` command with providing with correct password. Why does this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN0MX.png)
This was the manifest file that i used to deploy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.